# I need to execute some SQL files before running test suite in espresso

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-espresso

I use Android Espresso, Java and SQLite. Before running the test suite need to drop some tables, create them again and insert some data on them. I have the SQL scripts to perform these actions. How can I execute them before I run the test case?

Comment: In a `@Before` method in your test case class, use `SQLiteDatabase` to execute your SQL statements. I suspect that I am not understanding something about your question, though. Could you explain a bit more about what you need?

Comment: There's three tables I need to drop before test. Then I need to create them again and populate them with some specific data. I have three sql files. The first has the drop statement. The second has the create statement. And the third has the insert statements. So I need to execute them in this order before the execution of every test case.

Comment: Well, presumably, you already have code in your app for working with the database. So, reuse elements of that code from a `@Before` method in your test case class. Use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` to get a `Context` for the app under test, and use that `Context` when getting access to the database.